# Why is Visual Studio Code not finding my kubectl binary?

Tags: kubernetes, visual-studio-code

I restarted my mac (Mac OS High Sierra) and now Visual Studio code can't find kubectl binary even it is installed via brew.

```
$ which kubectl
/usr/local/bin/kubectl
```

[image]

The weird thing is that it could find kubectl before I restarted my laptop.

Answer (score 3):

adding the below config is vscode settings.json may resolve this

```
"vs-kubernetes": {
    "vscode-kubernetes.minikube-path.mac": "/path/to/minikube",
    "vscode-kubernetes.kubectl-path.mac": "/path/to/kubectl",
    "vscode-kubernetes.helm-path.mac" : "/path/to/helm"
}
```